# fixed snackBar in bottom of screen

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar, scaffold

i am new to dart
So i am frustrated by the snackBar is appears just in the footer of the body.
and above of persistentFooterButtons and bottomNavigationBar
plz someone help me to fixed the snackbar on the end of screen .

this my code:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(

  key: scaffoldKey,

  backgroundColor: Colors.white,

  appBar: AppBar(),

  body:  SafeArea(

          Material(

             color: Color(0xFF43bdd2), 

             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),

             child: MaterialButton(

                       onPressed:(){ _showSnack; },

                        child: Text('إرسال'),

                                  ),



                         ),  ),

  persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[

               Text('hello everyone'),

           ],

  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(

    child: Container(

      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),

          child: Text("©Copyright flutter 2020",style:   TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontWeight:     FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),



    ),  

  ),);}



         _showSnack(){scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:   Text('hi, here i am a snackBar'),)) ;}
```

Comment: Kindly, add a screen shot of what you got so far..and what do you want to get..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Flushbar to show a similar widget at the bottom.

```
FlatButton(
  child: Text('Show Snackbar'),
  onPressed: () {
    Flushbar(
      flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM, //Make sure at the bottom
    )
      ..title = 'hi, here i am a snackBar'
      ..show(context);
  },
),
```

Installing the package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar)

Add this in pubspec.ymal

```
dependencies:
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
```

Then import the flushber in the file you are on

```
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';
```